# Как безопасно посчитать введённую пользователем формулу?

Tags: python

Появилась задача считать произвольную формулу, вводимую пользователем. Требования:

- базовые математические операции и тригонометрические функции, 2+2*2 и прочая банальщина;
- поддержка чтения переменных, которые я передам в формулу;
- безопасность при любом пользовательском вводе (eval отпадает);
- ограничение времени выполнения, чтобы формула не подвесила всю программу своими вычислениями;
- условия, циклы присваивания и прочие радости жизни программиста необязательны, но были бы плюсом;
- производительность второстепенна: формулы будут простыми и редко вычисляемыми.

Сейчас я поглядел numexpr и asteval, но у обоих не удалось обнаружить вменяемое ограничение времени выполнения — `numexpr.evaluate('9**9**9')` вешает процесс целиком (и даже GIL не отпускает, гад такой). Тащить целый Lua или иной встраиваемый язык программирования не очень хочется. В принципе я бы мог изобрести свою реализацию с парсером и байткодом, но, может, всё-таки существуют соответствующие моим пожеланиям готовые решения? Или, может, в numexpr/asteval можно как-то ограничение по времени воткнуть?

Answer (score 1):

Выражение в нампи положи в тред, запускаешь в фон. В основном потоке ждёшь с таймаутом и убиваешь тред если таймаут райзнулся. На 5 строчек решение и не надо искать комбаин.

```
import numpy as np
import numexpr as ne

from multiprocessing import Pool, TimeoutError

def main():

    q="9**9**9"
    pool = Pool(processes=1)

    res = pool.apply_async(ne.evaluate, (q,))
    try:
        print(res.get(timeout=1))
    except TimeoutError:
        print("TimeoutError")
        pool.terminate()

main()
```

Comment: Я же написал, что GIL не отпускается - блокируются СРАЗУ ВСЕ потоки, я пробовал перед написанием вопроса.

Comment: @andreymal есть другая идея.

Comment: Но вот для asteval это наверно может даже прокатить, я не пробовал. Но всё равно костыль)

Comment: почему костыль?) это основы написания гуёв

Comment: @andreymal добавил рабочий код

Comment: Ну запуск отдельного процесса для вычисления простого выражения это уже совсем извращение) Но на вопрос отвечает)

Comment: Это может казаться извращением, но на самом деле форк не очень дорогой по ресурсам. Его можно переиспользовать.