Почему использовать eval() опасно?
Я пишу код для калькулятора (т.е., вписал пример и получил ответ).
Я нашёл способ использовать eval(), но говорят, что он опасен.
Чем он опасен и чем можно заменить его?

если в eval передается строка напрямую от пользователя - пользователь может ввести что угодно, а значит выполнить произвольный код

...напрмую от пользователя...
с помощью input(), что ли?

@максимум хоть через input, хоть из файла, хоть в http-запросе - разницы никакой. Всё равно можно вызвать деструктивные команды.

понял. чем тогда можно заменить eval()?

@максимум, все зависит от задачи. если вычислить выражение - одно решение, если что-то сложнее - другое. Можно либо написать самому, либо воспользоваться какими-то библиотеками, которые уже решают поставленную задачу

Кажется пора писать вопрос, чем можно заменить eval.

@StanislavVolodarskiy повод поныть про мой старый вопрос) https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1023756

@StanislavVolodarskiy тут есть примеры: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1166455/1365

Лучше всего в данном случае eval заменить переводом в и выполнением обратной польской записи.      Вот у меня проект есть: https://gitflic.ru/project/nchistov/translate-into-reverse-polish-notation

В контексте калькулятора, накидал простую проверку на безопасность входного выражения:
import math
import re

def safe_eval(string):
    allowed_chars = set('0123456789+-*/(). aceinopqstr')
    danger_keys = {'not', 'is', 'in', 'or', 'and', 'assert', 'raise', 'import', 'exec', 'eval', 'Ellipsis', 'as', 'case', 'pass'}

    if set(string) - allowed_chars:
        raise ValueError("Выражение содержит недопустимые символы")
    
    for keyword in danger_keys:
        if re.search(r'\b' + re.escape(keyword) + r'\b', string):
            raise ValueError("Выражение содержит недопустимые ключевые слова")

    return eval(string, {'__builtins__': {'sin': math.sin, 'cos': math.cos, 'tan': math.tan, 'sqrt': math.sqrt, 'pi': math.pi, 'e': math.e}})

safe = "sqrt(tan(54) - cos((2.8 + 3) * sin(pi / 4) + 10.5e-3))"
try:
    result = safe_eval(safe)
    print(f"Результат: {result}")
except Exception as e:
    print(f"Ошибка: {e}")

danger = "__import__('os').shutdown()"
try:
    result = safe_eval(danger)
    print(f"Результат: {type(result)}")
except Exception as e:
    print(f"Ошибка: {e}")


Запретили буквы - тригонометрическим функциям и научной нотации флоатов стало немножко грустно. Можно ли достать буквы, не имея прямого доступа к буквам - задачка интересная

@andreymal Да тут и флоаты в обычной нотации уже умерли ))  Точки же нет в допустимых символах. Хотя это легко поправимо.

@CrazyElf ну для флоатов можно хотя бы написать деление (314/100), но в любом случае - подход "запретить ваще всё" может даже и безопасный, только вот в использовании на практике становится немножко бесполезный (это примерно как "полностью защищённый компьютер - это выключенный компьютер")

Кстати, проверка на допустимые символы конечно делается проще/короче - через вычитание множеств: if set(string) - allowed_chars:

@CrazyElf воу, спасибо, я чтото о таком не додумался

Кстати () создаст пустой кортеж. Не знаю, влияет ли он на безопасность, но даже с такими злыми ограничениями это уже немножко больше чем тупой калькулятор)

@Amgarak Достаточно пройти несколько собеседований на алгоритмы - и такие вещи автоматом в голову приходить начинают )

@CrazyElf я пока только учусь, до собеседований ещё далеко

@andreymal интересное замечание, но я так и не придумал что можно сделать с tuple‍♀️

@andreymal я дополнил пример с учетом замечаний;)

@Amgarak теперь ждём когда в int/float/complex/tuple появится какой-нибудь метод с именем только из разрешённых букв)

@Amgarak стоило задать это как вопрос, а не постить вопрос в ответах.

Однако теперь стали доступны следующие ключевые слова: ... (Ellipsis), as, assert, case, in, is, or, pass, raise, not и вслед за ним целый bool — теперь это ещё меньше похоже на калькулятор)

@andreymal да не вопрос, это мы тоже можем пофиксить. Дополнил ответ)

@Amgarak и вот такими темпами, постепенно наращивая функциональность «калькулятора», вы однажды забудете что-нибудь пофиксить, поэтому не надо так)

@andreymal Для чего-то же этот инструмент добавили? А так можно договориться о том, что на сайтах лучше базы данных не использовать, а то забудешь что-то пофиксить и злобный хакер внедрит свой  SQL injection...

@Amgarak в современных библиотеках для работы с sql есть средства для защиты от инъекций. Потому что в любом случае в запросы нужно как-то данные подставлять, и никаких альтернатив sql по сути нет. А здесь eval/exec есть, просто потому что есть. На их основе легко сделать REPL (вторая буква - буквально Eval), но на практике для чего-то другого использовать не нужно. Тем более что безопасные альтернативы есть, и даже свое не сильно сложнее написать, чем eval обвешать всевозможными защитами.

В целом, с точки зрения безопасности - лучше изначально разрешить только нужную функциональность, чем сначала разрешить все, а потом все небезопасное пытаться запретить, и надеяться, что все корнер кейсы учел.

@insolor написание безопасной альтернативы для eval/exec потребует значительных усилий и желательно глубокого понимания безопасности и особенностей языка(чем я лично не обладаю). Так что для меня это далеко «не сильно сложнее». На мой вкус, вы через чур демонизируете данный функционал.

@Amgarak 1 - просто не нужно давать пользователю выполнять произвольный код на самом интерпретаторе Python, нужен свой интерпретатор со строго ограниченным функционалом (причем интерпретатор не языка Python, а интерпретатор выражений). 2 - есть готовые безопасные альтернативы: numexpr, simpleeval. 3 - вы слишком безалаберно относитесь к информационной безопасности.

@insolor за второй пункт спасибо, обязательно ознакомлюсь

Посмотрите еще у gil9red на гитхабе примеры: https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/tree/master/calculator

Документация python:
eval(expression, globals=None, locals=None)

Параметры:
expression (str | code object) – Python выражение (Проще Python код)
...

Аргумент expression анализируется и оценивается как Python выражение (Проще Python код) ...

То есть, eval буквально позволяет выполнить все, что вы в него сунете. Представьте, как пользователь вашего калькулятора пишет в поле ввода os.shutdown(). Ваш код:
expression = input()
eval(exspression)

Expression выполнится, компьютер выключится, а вы останетесь без преданного пользователя.
Безусловно, звучит как анекдот. В своем калькуляторе вы можете использовать eval без угрызений совести, так как ответственность за ввод - вы. Но в реальных проектах eval следует использовать с осторожностью.
При желании eval можно заменить простой функцией, к примеру:
def main():
    expression = input()

    first_number = ""
    index = 0

    while expression[index].isdigit():
        first_number += expression[index]
        index += 1

    operator = expression[index]
    second_number = expression[index+1:]

    if operator == "+":
        print(int(first_number) + int(second_number))
    elif operator == "-":
        print(int(first_number) - int(second_number))
    elif operator == "*":
        print(int(first_number) * int(second_number))
    elif operator == "/":
        print(int(first_number) / int(second_number))


Вот только если os не импортирована в модуль - ничего не произойдёт... да и зону видимости eval() можно ограничить, да и ввод сперва проверить тоже можно. В общем, аргументы так себе.

@Amgarak, пример скорее для наглядности, чем для практики)) Конечно eval не такой всемогущий, но сути моих слов не меняет - eval в промышленной разработке нужно использовать аккуратно

@Amgarak ну написать __import__("os") вообще не проблема

@Amgarak и «ввод сперва проверить» тоже не получится — если только запрещать опасное, то однажды в любом случае всё равно найдётся лазейка, а если только разрешать неопасное, то это по сложности получится что-то на уровне мини-языка программирования и в использовании eval уже просто пропадёт смысл

@andreymal вот только при использовании eval() с импортированием модулями, они не становятся автоматически доступными в глобальной области видимости для последующих вызовов  eval(). Так что хоть объимпортируйся - толку будет НОЛЬ (os.shutdown() - не сработает). К тому же сложные конструкции в eval() не передать, только выражения (это вам не exec()). А если мы говори об математике, то проверить строку на лишние символы, это что-то на уровне мини языка?

@Amgarak написать __import__("os").shutdown() вообще не проблема, да и написать даже eval('exec("import os; os.shutdown()")') тоже вообще не проблема, области видимости не имеют никакого значения, и в любом случае с помощью выражений можно сделать очень многое. Покажите вашу проверку на «лишние» символы, а я попробую придумать как её обойти

@andreymal с выражениями согласен, дал маху - сам уже опробовал. Но сейчас подумаю о примере.

@andreymal вызываю вас)

@Amgarak, в отрывке документации Python, который я предоставил в своем ответе написано что python расценивает первый аргумент как Python выражение, и все) Больше никаких ограничений не упомянуто (Разве что говорится о аргументах globals и locals)

@Justiks и вот как раз через эти дополнительные аргументы можно очень не плохо бустануть защиту eval() от всякого страшного.

окей окей)) eval("import os; os.system('sudo rm -rf / --no-preverse-root')")

@Justiks и получите SyntaxError: invalid syntax

@Justiks print(eval("__import__('os').getcwd()")) - вот так сработает. А если вот так уже нет - eval("__import__('os').getcwd()",{"__builtins__": None})  Фактически без проблем можно управлять тем что можно использовать и что использовать нельзя.

@Justiks import math; print(eval("sin(7)",{"__builtins__": None}, {'sin': math.sin})) - вот попытайтесь вместо "sin(7)" что-то импортировать и запустить что-то своё.

@Amgarak если не брать в расчёт вашу фильтрацию по символам, то всё это очень легко обходится — (x for x in ().__class__.__base__.__subclasses__() if 'load_module' in x.__dict__).__next__().load_module('builtins').__import__('os').getcwd()

@andreymal оо, это очень интересно, обязательно изучу ваш пример!)
